# Storing class names in variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta washere="fgras">
    <title>Mesure de Distance - Page 1</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        
        
        <!-- ****************** Table ****************** -->
        
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }

        tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        th {
            background-color: darkslategray;
            color: white;
        }
        
        
        body{
            font-family:arial;
        }
        
        .valHP {
            background-color: #A0A0A0;
                }

        .valError {
            background-color: #FF00FF;
                }

        .valInsideGood {
            color: #00A000;
            }

        .valInsideBad {
            color: #FF0000;
        }
        
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var requestNumber=0;
        var value1Node = null;
        var value2Node = null;
        
        function onData(e, xhr){
            try{
                console.log("onData.event =",e);
                console.log("onData.xhr =",xhr);
                var data = xhr.responseText;
                console.log("data =",data);
                data = data.split("|");
                
                var value1 = Number(data[1]);
                var value2 = Number(data[2]);
                
                value1Node.textContent = value1;
                value2Node.textContent = value2;

                if(value1==0){
                    value1Node.className="valHP";
                    value1Node.textContent="--";
                }else if(value1>=26 && value1<=28){
                    value1Node.className="valInsideBad";
                }else if(value1>28 && value1<=34){
                    value1Node.className="valInsideGood";
                }else{
                    value1Node.className="valError";
                    value1Node.textContent="err";
                }
                
                
            }finally{
                setTimeout(refreshData,200);
            }
        }
        
        function refreshData(){
            requestNumber++;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener("load", (function(e){return onData(e, xhr);}));
            xhr.open("GET", "data.html?t="+requestNumber); //t pour un nom de page unique et éviter le cache
            xhr.send();
        }
        function onPageLoad(){
            value1Node = document.getElementById("val1");

            
            refreshData();
        }
        
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onPageLoad()">


<div class="table100-body js-pscroll"> 
    <table style="width:50%">
        <thead>
        <tr class="row100 head">
            <th class="cell100 column1">Colonne1</th>
            <th class="cell100 column2">Colonne2</th>
            <th class="cell100 column3">Colonne3</th>
            <th class="cell100 column4">Colonne4</th>
            <th class="cell100 column5">Colonne5</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="row100-body">
            <td class="cellColumn"> <span id="val1"></span></td>
            <td class="cellColumn"> Capteur 1= </td>
            <td class="cellColumn"> Distance_Capt_1</td>
            <td class="cellColumn"> Distance_Capt_1</td>
            <td class="cellColumn"> Distance_Capt_1</td>
        </tr>
        

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div> 
    
</body>
```

I'm trying to display a data that i receive from a hardware on a web page in a table.
Based on what range my received datas are in, I need to display them with red and green colors.

I have defined 4 classes using CSS.

In my html part, inside a table i want to assign classes to td blocks, but my classes are stored in a variabale (value1Node.className)
I tried `td class=value1Node.className` and it doesn't work.
I also put `value1Node.className` in "" and '' and it didn't work.
how can i do this?
(All other parts of code works just fine)

data is stored in value1 and i have 3 ifs in javascript:

```js
if (value1 == 0) {
  value1Node.className = "valHP";
  value1Node.textContent = "Out of Range";
} else if (value1 >= 26 && value1 <= 28) {
  value1Node.className = "valInsideBad";
} else if (value1 > 28 && value1 <= 34) {
  value1Node.className = "valInsideGood";
} else {
  value1Node.className = "valError";
  value1Node.textContent = "err";
}
```

```css
.valHP {
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
}

.valError {
  background-color: #FF00FF;
}

.valInsideGood {
  color: #00A000;
}

.valInsideBad {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: please show how do you build your `td` elements

Comment: Please create a complete and working snippet with tools `<>`

Comment: What is value2Node?

Comment: Why update every 200 ms - that is likely too fast for the server

Comment: value2Node is for the second data that i haven't started coding yet. the 200 ms is too fast i i know but data changes so fast and this web page is going to be for surveillance. im working with hardwares

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 *custom-data* attributes are designed for this purpose.

Instead of:

- `class="valHP"`
- `class="valError"`
- `class="valInsideGood"`
- `class="valInsideBad"`

You can have:

- `data-my-value="HP"`
- `data-my-value="Error"`
- `data-my-value="InsideGood"`
- `data-my-value="InsideBad"`

and then in your CSS you can have:

```
[data-my-value="HP"] {
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
}

[data-my-value="Error"] {
  background-color: #FF00FF;
}

[data-my-value="InsideGood"] {
  color: #00A000;
}

[data-my-value="InsideBad"] {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

***Then***, in your javascript, you can have:

```
if (value1 === 0) {
  value1Node.setAttribute('data-my-value', 'valHP');
  value1Node.textContent = "Out of Range";
} else if (value1 >= 26 && value1 <= 28) {
  value1Node.setAttribute('data-my-value', 'InsideBad');
} else if (value1 > 28 && value1 <= 34) {
  value1Node.setAttribute('data-my-value', 'InsideGood');
} else {
  value1Node.setAttribute('data-my-value', 'Error');
  value1Node.textContent = "err";
}
```

If at any point you wish to query the value of `data-value`, you can use `dataset`:

```
value1Node.dataset.myValue  // returns data-my-value
```

You can also directly **set** each value via `dataset`:

```
value1Node.dataset.myValue = 'InsideGood'; // Now: data-my-value="InsideGood"
```

Knowing this, you can now script the following:

```
if (value1 === 0) {
  value1Node.data.myValue = 'valHP';
  value1Node.textContent = "Out of Range";
} else if (value1 >= 26 && value1 <= 28) {
  value1Node.data.myValue = 'InsideBad';
} else if (value1 > 28 && value1 <= 34) {
  value1Node.data.myValue = 'InsideGood';
} else {
  value1Node.data.myValue = 'Error';
  value1Node.textContent = "err";
}
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes
- https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/10/using-data-attributes-in-javascript-and-css/

Comment: Thanks. the problem is, i don't know: data-my-value = ?
because the data is coming in real time, it changes and i need the td class to be automatically defined by the code itself.

Comment: could you take a look at the full snipet code that i added?